# Scala Nested HashMaps, how to access Case Class value properties?

Tags: scala, hashmap, case-class

New to Scala, continue to struggle with `Option` related code.  I have a HashMap built of Case Class instances that themselves contain hash maps with Case Class instance values. It is not clear to me how to access properties of the retrieved Class instances:

```
import collection.mutable.HashMap

case class InnerClass(name: String, age: Int)
case class OuterClass(name: String, nestedMap: HashMap[String, InnerClass])

// Load some data...hash maps are mutable
val innerMap = new HashMap[String, InnerClass]()
innerMap += ("aaa" -> InnerClass("xyz", 0))

val outerMap = new HashMap[String, OuterClass]()
outerMap += ("AAA" -> OuterClass("XYZ", innerMap))

// Try to retrieve data
val outerMapTest = outerMap.getOrElse("AAA", None)
val nestedMap = outerMapTest.nestedMap
```

This produces `error: value nestedMap is not a member of Option[ScalaFiddle.OuterClass]`

```
// Try to retrieve data a different way
val outerMapTest = outerMap.getOrElse("AAA", None)
val nestedMap = outerMapTest.nestedMap
```

This produces `error: value nestedMap is not a member of Product with Serializable`

Please advise on how I would go about getting access to `outerMapTest.nestedMap`.  I'll eventually need to get values and properties out of the `nestedMap` HashMap as well.

Comment: You don't need to check for if the key exists and return None. A HashMap will return None if the key doesn't exist. Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `.getOrElse("someKey", None)` which returns you a type `Product` (not the actual type as you expect to be `OuterClass`)

```
scala> val outerMapTest = outerMap.getOrElse("AAA", None)
outerMapTest: Product with Serializable = OuterClass(XYZ,Map(aaa -> InnerClass(xyz,0)))
```

so `Product` either needs to be pattern matched or casted to `OuterClass`

pattern match example

```
scala> outerMapTest match { case x : OuterClass => println(x.nestedMap); case _ => println("is not outerclass") }
Map(aaa -> InnerClass(xyz,0))
```

Casting example which is a terrible idea when outerMapTest is `None`, (pattern matching is favored over casting)

```
scala> outerMapTest.asInstanceOf[OuterClass].nestedMap
res30: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,InnerClass] = Map(aaa -> InnerClass(xyz,0))
```

**But better way of solving it would simply use `.get`** which very smart and gives you `Option[OuterClass]`,

```
scala> outerMap.get("AAA").map(outerClass => outerClass.nestedMap)
res27: Option[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,InnerClass]] = Some(Map(aaa -> InnerClass(xyz,0)))
```

For key that does not exist, gives you `None`

```
scala> outerMap.get("I dont exist").map(outerClass => outerClass.nestedMap)
res28: Option[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,InnerClass]] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you can take to get deep inside a nested structure like this.

```
outerMap.lift("AAA")             // Option[OuterClass]
        .map(_.nestedMap)        // Option[HashMap[String,InnerClass]]
        .flatMap(_.lift("aaa"))  // Option[InnerClass]
        .map(_.name)             // Option[String]
        .getOrElse("no name")    // String
```

Notice that if either of the inner or outer maps doesn't have the specified key ("aaa" or "AAA" respectively) then the whole thing will safely result in the default string ("no name").

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap` will return `None` if a `key` is not found so it is unnecessary to do `getOrElse` to return `None` if the key is not found.

A simple solution to your problem would be to use get only as below

Change your first `get` as

```
val outerMapTest = outerMap.get("AAA").get
```

you can check the output as

```
println(outerMapTest.name)
println(outerMapTest.nestedMap)
```

And change the second `get` as

```
val nestedMap = outerMapTest.nestedMap.get("aaa").get
```

You can test the outputs as

```
println(nestedMap.name)
println(nestedMap.age)
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks - this mostly works.  To get the nested map values I need to `println(nestedMap.get("aaa").get.name)`

Comment: @rgwozdz Great to hear that it helped you inspite of best answers above. Thanks for upvoting. :)

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
val maybeInner = outerMap.get("AAA").flatMap(_.nestedMap.get("aaa"))
val maybeName = maybeInner.map(_.name)
```

Which if your feeling adventurous you can get with

```
val name: String = maybeName.get
```

But that will throw an error if its not there. If its a `None`

Answer (score 0):

you can access the nestMap using below expression.

```
scala> outerMap.get("AAA").map(_.nestedMap).getOrElse(HashMap())
res5: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,InnerClass] = Map(aaa -> InnerClass(xyz,0))
```

if `"AAA"` didnt exist in the outerMap Map object then the below expression would have returned an empty HashMap as indicated in the `.getOrElse` method argument (`HashMap()`).